# Create IOS datepicker like select element in Ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

Is there a way to create an ios datepicker/timepicker like styled custom select for ionic apps?

For example, I want to create a custom select as the following image

[image: iPhone date picker]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of late to the party, but maybe this will help: https://github.com/mmnaseri/proton.multi-list-picker

This is an Angular 1.x component with no dependencies on any other frameworks that provides an easy solution for creating iOS-style select views.

For instance, this is the sort of select that you can create with this component:

[image]

And this is another example:

[image]

If you set the attachment value to `bottom` it will be exactly like the iOS select component looks like, with a fixed bottom modal attachment.

Comment: @PetterFriberg thanks for the comment! will update now.

Comment: This is the exact answer for this question even though you are late to the party. Thanks for the answer ;-)

Comment: Thank you :) If you would be so kind as to accept this answer then, other people might find this solution pertinent to their situation as well.

Comment: Done. Accepted as the answer :)

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, does anyone know if there is an Angular2 version of this component?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but for now this not possible with Ionic. There options like this [ionic-datepicker](https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-datepicker), but this isn't native, just a library.

Answer (score 1):

There are various plugins available out there. You can find [one here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/datePicker/)

Also you can use HTML `Select/Option` list to show up a native alike control that will display a list of single select-able items. `Select/Option` tag invokes  OS specific native selector.

Have a look at it [here](http://demo.mobiscroll.com/select/select). That demo might help you.

Comment: What I want is to design a list(a list of options) with a similar style. Is that possible?

Comment: I believe you have very less control over styling these list-option elements as these are displayed in native picker.

Native picker will display the list in a very similar manner as you mentioned in the question above, without much styling required. Give it a try.